# How to connect database with browser in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password: "123",
        database: "mydb"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var sql = "SELECT users.name AS user, products.name AS favorite FROM users JOIN products ON users.favorite_product = products.id";

        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('hello world');
        });
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Please also mention what problem you are getting after running this

Comment: its not working mean to say browser just revolve but not loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass the sql query into a nodejs web server then give the result as a respond.

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "123",
  database: "mydb"
});
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var query = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql = unescape(query.sql);
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
      });
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

then you just call

```js
var sql = escape("select * from table")
```

http://localhost:8080/?sql=select%20*%20from%20table

Answer (score 1):

No no no.

You cant put these codes into frontend.

Frontend codes are not being compiled, they are interpreted languages. So anyone who open your website will be see your DB address, user and pass.

Here is what you should do;

1. put there codes backend ( so run them on server-side )
2. create an restful api to serve data with json.
3. put some ajax call on frontend website and connect the api you created.

This is how web works.